# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'doc

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

i am a beginner and i trying to model system dynamic model using python programming.the problem is when i trying to print the components of the sd model, the error message comes out like this:

```
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'doc'"
```

my code:

```
import pysd    

educationmodel = pysd.read_vensim('Education.mdl')     
print educationmodel.components.doc()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand from the git repo, the `doc()` method is inside `Class PySD`. Also, `read_vensim` returns an instance of this class.

So your problem should get solved if you directly use `educationmodel.doc()`.

Comment: i run the code but it still comes out with error: "AttributeError: 'PySD' object has no attribute 'doc' " but i try to change the code by: print educationmodel.components, the output comes out like this :runfile('C:/Users/STUDENT/.spyder2/education-sd.py', wdir='C:/Users/STUDENT/.spyder2')
Reloaded modules: 147073311549
<module '147073322601' from 'Education.py'>. can you please explain it to me..tqqq

Answer (score 0):

That may be my fault - I had to move the `.doc()` function to the model object instead of the components object as a way to work towards including Vensim macros properly. If it's still an issue, may want to update to the latest release (0.7.4). If that doesn't help either, then we may have to fix something. =)